# Getting Exception "document is open" while generating pdf

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, tiff

I'm trying to convert tiff file to pdf using iTextSharp library and getting this exception.
**`"document is open"`**

Here is my code:

```
Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*"
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
     ' creation of the document with a certain size and certain margins  
        Dim document As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0)


        ' load the tiff image and count the total pages  
        Dim bm As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim total As Integer = bm.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page)

        document.Open()
        ' creation of the different writers  
        Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))

        Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        For k As Integer = 0 To total - 1
            bm.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, k)
            Dim img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            ' scale the image to fit in the page  
            img.ScalePercent(72.0F / img.DpiX * 100)
            img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0)
            cb.AddImage(img)
            document.NewPage()
        Next k
        document.Close()
```

Can anyone say me what and where am I going wrong ?

**EDIT:**

When I tried to add the dimensions:

```
img.ScaleToFit(595, 842)
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening at? I almost bet from the looks of it at: Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))

Comment: yes exactly. can you say me why and what do I need to do now?\

Comment: From the looks of it, you followed this example? http://atashbahar.com/post/Converting-Multipage-TIFF-image-to-PDF.aspx ; correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Or this one; http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Converting-Fax-Tiff-to-PDF-td4186863.html ?

Comment: no..the one you said before http://atashbahar.com/post/Converting-Multipage-TIFF-image-to-PDF.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explain in [my book about iText](http://itextpdf.com/book/), you should create a PDF in 5 steps when using iText(Sharp). Creating the `writer` is step 2 and opening the document is step 3. You have switched these two steps and this is what causes the error.

You need to move the line `document.Open()` down a couple of lines. After where you create the `writer` and before creating the `cb` instance.

Comment: Jst now I was going through it and luckily got ur answer..Many thnks for that and one more doubt is that when adding tiff file it dosent scale the image as I need to fit the image. I have tried using img.ScalePercent(24.0F) but the image is generated at center. can you say me how do I need to modify it.

Comment: You're creating A4 pages and you're adding images of unknown size. If I were you, I'd resize the image so that it fits an A4 page: `img.ScaleToFit(595, 842);` The values 595 and 842 are the width and the height of an A4 page. The `ScaleToFit()` method will preserve the aspect ratio of the image. If that's not necessary, you can use `img.ScaleAbsolute(595, 842);` (but obviously that will distort image with a different aspect ratio). Don't forget `img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);` to add the image at the bottom!

Comment: when I tried to add the dimensions said by you I get result as shown above. Why do I get a white space on top of image ? and last but not the least can I include this dll in my commercial project or do we need to pay?

Comment: (1) What is the aspect ratio of your image? If the height is much smaller than the width, the result you get is normal. (2) iTextSharp is published under the AGPL. If you create a commercial project, a license is needed. Fill out the sales form for more info: http://itextpdf.com/sales

Comment: its a tiff file with 1066 * 1155 pixels

Comment: In that case it's normal that you'll have a white border on top, because `ScaleToFit()` will resize the image into an image measuring 595 by 644.676 pt. The reason for the white margin should be obvious. It's a matter of really simple math. The top border is 197.32 pt (or 2.74 inch if you prefer to measure in inches). Surely you don't need to be familiar with iTextSharp to understand that ;-)